# Three translation suggestions for the experience part on the French version of Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

I'm filling the experience part of the form of my Careers page and I'm surprised by two translations.

[image: Experience]

### 1

On the English version, the label is **Job Title** while it is **Titre de l'offre** in French. The problem is that **offre** implies that it is a job offer. This is not a job offer, this is a job title.

I think this label should be renamed to **Titre du poste**.

### 2

**chez** is a translation of **to** in a spatial context (and other contexts not listed here), but not when it is about time. In this context, **to** should be translated as **à**.

But this is still strange in French language (this is my personal opinion), another label is usually added before the first field, to end up with:

> **De** [start fields] **à** [end fields]

which is a translation of:

> **From** [start fields] **to** [end fields]

### 3 (update)

English:

[image: Markdown]

French:

[image: Texte]

**Markdown** is replaced by **Texte**, it should be **Markdown** in these 2 languages.

Comment: Remove the "Markdown" in your translation.csv file, Then try it

Comment: @user2277313 what is this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. done
2. changed "to", but did not add the "from" (that's on the backlog now)
3. done

Comment: Nice, thanks. The *from* was cosmetic, *à* is enough to understand the role of this field.